# PHP remainder (%-operator) unexpected results

Tags: php

```
# PHP Version 5.2.9  

$a = 0.6/0.1;  
$b = $a % 5;  
print "\$a=$a; \$b=$b\n";  
# result:  
# $a=6; $b=0   # One should expect $b = 1  

$a = 0.6/0.1;  
$a = round($a);  
$b = $a % 5;  
print "\$a=$a; \$b=$b\n";  
# result:  
# $a=6; $b=1  # result as expected
```

Why is the result $b=0 in the first case.
And why does the round()-function seems to solve the problem?

Comment: In PHP modulus can only be used on integers https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=34399

Comment: Try casting to `int` first.

Comment: Operands of modulus are converted to integers (by stripping the decimal part) before processing. - http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

Comment: @MikeB I agree with the PHP folks who say this isn't a bug.

Answer (score 3):

Print both numbers with a bunch of decimal places and you'll see the problem, which is due to [floating point imprecision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems):

The first `$a`:

```
5.999999999999999111821580299874767661
```

The second, after `round()`:

```
6.000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Casting the first to `int` (like the mod operator does when it computes its value) results in `5`, while the second results in `6`.